# Plyer "NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!"

Tags: python

I am tryin to send desktop notifications with python, and was trying to run a test code but this error showed up. I have already installed pip and plyer. I am using a Mac if it helps.

For reference, I was following this [tutorial](https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-send-desktop-notifications-with-python-62a738850fbf)

Code:

```
from plyer import notification

notification.notify(
    title = 'testing',
    message = 'message',
    app_icon = None,
    timeout = 10,
）
```

Please do let me know if I did anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, it is not implemented.

You can see it in the code [here](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/630457fb716e65304c023471cc48d0e12b19932c/plyer/facades/notification.py#L93):

```
    self._notify(
        title=title, message=message,
        app_icon=app_icon, app_name=app_name,
        timeout=timeout, ticker=ticker, toast=toast, hints=hints
    )

# private

def _notify(self, **kwargs):
    raise NotImplementedError("No usable implementation found!")
```